# Getting substrings in LuaU

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

the title might look very stupid but I really can't find out what the problem is, I have created a custom function to substring like the way in C++ because I like it:

```lua
local function SubStr(String, Start, Count)
    return String:sub(Start, Start+(Count-1))
end
```

This is the code I am using, the substring function seems to work for the Bit Depth, Width and height, though when reading the colour values, it seems to offset a ton and I'm not sure what it is:

```lua
        print("BitDepth", SubStr(Text, 1, 8))
        print("Width", SubStr(Text, 9, 8))
        print("Height", SubStr(Text, 17, 8))
        
        Image["BitDepth"] = tonumber(SubStr(Text, 1, 8), 2)
        Image["Width"] = tonumber(SubStr(Text, 9, 8), 2)
        Image["Height"] = tonumber(SubStr(Text, 17, 8), 2)

        for i = 1, Image["BitDepth"] do
            Image["Colours"] = {};
            Image["Colours"][i] = {};
            
            print("RED", SubStr(Text, (24*i), 8))
            print("BLUE", SubStr(Text, (24*i)+8, 8))
            print("GREEN", SubStr(Text, (24*i)+16, 8))
            print("ALPHA", SubStr(Text, (24*i)+24, 8))
```

[image]

The intended binary colour values for when `i` = `1`, should all be `11111111`

By the way this is reading the following binary string:

`000000110000100000001000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000011111111`

Comment: What string is the `Text`?

Comment: Did you calculate what `(24*i)` is equal to?

Comment: Imagine you had to get the red/blue/green/alpha by only typing numbers in SubStr instead of calculations. What numbers would you have to use? Does your program use those numbers or does it use different numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes; test this out. The first offset start at 25 and second offset start from multiples of 32.

```lua
-- New v**strong text**ariables
offset = 25
count = 0; -- count is essentially (i - 1)
for i = 1, Image["BitDepth"] do
    Image["Colours"] = {};
    Image["Colours"][i] = {};
    
    print(i)
    -- first_offset + second_offset + third_offset
    print("RED", SubStr(Text, offset + (32*count), 8))
    print("BLUE", SubStr(Text, offset + (32*count)+8, 8))
    print("GREEN", SubStr(Text, offset + (32*count)+16, 8))
    print("ALPHA", SubStr(Text, offset + (32*count)+24, 8))
    count = count + 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

3x8 is 24. So the next value starts at 25, not 24.